# Is patch extraction an important step before training deep neural networks?

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am trying to implement the following paper : 
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8281622

In this paper patch extraction process has been carried out before training of the convolutional denoising autoencoder model. I wanted to know if this step is necessary or I can train on the whole image as well. What differences will it make?

Comment: Depends, is your image defect free? That's the preprocessing step and the reason they extract patches.

Comment: Yes the images from which they have extracted patches are defect free.

Comment: Then should be fine. I suspect the authors of the paper wanted to get more normality data, so they used patches from images with defects.

Comment: Hey Matthieu thank you for your comment. What the authors have actually done is that they have taken only defect free images for training of CAE Model so that the model can learn the patterns in defect free images and hence when we pass any defected image to this trained CAE it gives us a residual error.